# Using regex to get multiple number in string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have 3 strings

1. "1:1 (1 stock – 1 voting right)"
2. "1 stock – 1 voting right"
3. "01 stock – 01 voting right"

How can i get all the numbers in string and return it to format "num:num" when I use regex in Python. Can you give me a general regex to process all case?
Example:
If case is first string, it will return 1:1 because it already have 1:1
If case is in other, it will also return 1:1
Thank you

Comment: A regular expression can only match a contiguous substring. It can't return characters that aren't in the string. So you can't return `1:1` if there's no `1:1` in the string.

Comment: You can use capture groups to capture `1` and `1` from the other strings, and use other formatting operations to combine them with `:`.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents assuming:

- At least two **integers** seperated by at least a single non-number;
- Order of appearance of these integers is kept as input for 1st:2nd integer in final format;
- Remove possible leading zeros from integers.

Try:

```
^\D*0*(\d+)\D+0*(\d+).*$
```

Replace with `\1:\2`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFuDHm/1)

---

The above would match:

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `\D*0*` - 0+ (Greedy) non-digits followed by 0+ zeros to prevent the following capture group from holding leading zeros;
- `(\d+)` - A 1st capture group to catch the 1st integer of 1+ digits;
- `\D+0*` - 1+ (Greedy) non-digits followed by 0+ zeros to prevent the following capture group from holding leading zeros;
- `(\d+)` - A 2nd capture group to catch the 1st integer of 1+ digits;
- `.*$` - 0+ (Greedy) characters upto end-line anchor.